# Does the amount of data stored in the memory (e.g. DDR3) affect its power consumption?

Tags: memory, memory-management

I am not familiar with memory principles. This may be a naive question.

Suppose I have a DRAM with 1GB, like the one in my tablet.

Will there be power consumption differences when it holds 200MB data, or 500MB data?

Comment: This question belongs to superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is just present in memory and not being accessed, No.

But the power consumption will increase in following cases:

1. You read memory - uses read circuit - very likely that you will read data when it is present in the memory
2. When you alter/write memory - large consumption when  bit alterations in cells take place from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0

Also, there is a constant leakage current at all time the device is on.